# GNU Make Simply Expanded Variables and Automatic Variables

Tags: makefile, go, cross-compiling, gnu-make

I have a fairly simple makefile for a Go project and I want to be able to run something akin to:
    make release-all

in order to build releases for a couple of different platforms (e.g. windows, linux, darwin).

My make file currently looks like this:

```
GOOSES = darwin windows linux
GOARCHS = amd64 386
.PHONY: release-all $(GOOSES) $(GOARCHS)
release: $(GOOSES)

$(GOOSES): GOOS := app $@
$(GOOSES): $(GOARCHS)

$(GOARCHS): GOARCH := $@
$(GOARCHS): build

build:
GOOS=$(GOOS) GOARCH=$(GOARCH) go install ...
```

When I actually try to build though, I get:

```
GOOS= GOARCH= go install ...
```

So as far as I can tell the `:=` isn't causing the `$@` to be evaluated on assignment. Is this possible to acheive somehow? If not, all I basically want to do is iterate over each item in list of OS'es and then over each of the architectures until I've built all the options. Is that at least possible without specifying each architecture/os combo explicitly?

Comment: The simple answer is that automatic variables (e.g. `$@`) aren't available in the prerequisite list, but... It's *really* unclear how you expect this makefile to work. Does a command like `GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go install...` actually work?

Comment: Yup, the "..." is obviously redacted for now, but it works just fine for building go programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your command works, this will handle the iteration:

```
GOOSES = darwin windows linux
GOARCHS = amd64 386

build:

define template
build: build_$(1)_$(2)
.PHONY: build_$(1)_$(2)
build_$(1)_$(2):
    GOOS=$(1) GOARCH=$(2) go install ...
endef

$(foreach GOARCH,$(GOARCHS),$(foreach GOOS,$(GOOSES),$(eval $(call template,$(GOOS),$(GOARCH)))))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, that works like a charm. What is the `$(1)_$(2)` syntax/feature called so I can read more on it?

Comment: @simpleproof: See the manual sections on [canned recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) and [the `call` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function).